# What are these two white screws on a ps3 power supply?

Tags: power-supply

In [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GapgMlj_6H8&feature=player_embedded) a gentlemen turns two white screws to fix a play station 3 not turning on anymore.  Could anyone tell me what these screws are, and what turning them a little bit is supposed to solve?

[image: screen grab of the "white screws"]

Comment: They look like [trim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trimmer_(electronics)) pots but I can't tell what they're for.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They are trim pots for OCP, or Over Current Protection, and PFC, or Power Factor Correction.

They are usually used to adjust things at the factory, because a batch of parts like resistors can vary slightly even though they have the same ratings.

Either they werent adjusted right at the factory, or parts may be starting to wear out requiring adjustment.

Comment: "PFC +B" might adjust the PFC output voltage?  "B+" is a common label for voltage supply rails, though I have no idea why.